# Ember Data not properly serializing property names of objects in an array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ember.js, ember-data

I have a simple (made up for this question) model with an attribute called electricGuitars that has a few defaults predefined.

```
 export default class guitarCollectionModel extends Model {
  @attr('string') firstName;
  @attr('string') lastName;
  @attr({
    defaultValue() {
      return [
        {
          serialNumber: "sdfdsfadf",
          colorCode: "dsfsadfdfa"
        },
        {
          serialNumber: "234234234",
          colorCode: "234234234323"
        },
        {
          serialNumber: "oorprpprprpororprp",
          colorCode: "rproproroprporp"
        }
      ];
    }
  }) electricGuitars;
}
```

When I save the model (`this.model.save()`) Ember Data POSTs to my API and *almost* everything is serialized correctly by default (no custom serializer or adpaters). API expects all property names to be dasherized.

```
{
  "data": {
    "attributes": {
      "first-name": null,
      "last-name": null,
      "electric-guitars": [
        {
          "serialNumber": "sdfdsfadf",
          "colorCode": "dsfsadfdfa"
        },
        {
          "serialNumber": "234234234",
          "colorCode": "234234234323"
        },
        {
          "serialNumber": "oorprpprprpororprp",
          "colorCode": "rproproroprporp"
        }
      ]
    },
    "type": "guitar-collection"
  }
}
```

The problem is that the `serialNumber` and `colorCode` properties inside of the `electricGuitars` property/array have *not* been dasherized.

Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

While JSON:API [supports](https://jsonapi.org/format/#document-resource-object-attributes) any valid JSON as an attribute value, Ember Data serialisers don’t apply to nested complex objects. You may find [Ember Data Model Fragments](https://github.com/adopted-ember-addons/ember-data-model-fragments) of use for this, or [embedded records](https://davidtang.io/2016-01-29-working-with-nested-data-in-ember-data-models/#3-embedded-records).

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to write a custom [transform](https://api.emberjs.com/ember-data/release/classes/Transform). In the `serialize` function you could dasherize:

```js
serialize(deserialized) {
  return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(deserialized)
    .map(([key, val]) => [dasherize(key), val])
  )
}
```

then specify the custom transform:

```
@attr('my-custom-transform', {
```